# How can I make the Electron welcome screen to stop showing on session start?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron app configured to open at login using Electron api, like this:

```
app.setLoginItemSettings({
    openAtLogin: true,
    path: app.getPath('exe')
});
```

But every time the user logs in, the Electron "welcome screen" is displayed both with the window of my app. How can I stop this from happening?

I used electron-builder for creating the nsis installer (Windows).

Comment: (The industry term is "[splash screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen)" btw). Electron doesn't show a splash screen by default - what other code do you have in your project?

Comment: It sounds like the electron framework is installed on the users computer? Have you tried installing on a computer which has no previous installation of Electron or anything?

Comment: @Garmien why would it open when electron is installed? This makes it super hard for developers to test the actual user experience

Comment: @Tom If you install the Electron development framework on a computer, it starts with computer as default. You can disable it from Startup processes in task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the window was appearing because the framework was also installed in the computer; as @Garmien commented.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a solution to me. How to stop this from happening?